# ngClass not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to AngularJS and I understand that the ngClass directive can be used to insert classes dynamically into elements like:

```
<input ng-class="{some-class: condition, another-class: anotherCondition}">
```

And angular will automatically evaluate which conditions  are true and will insert those particular classes in the element.

Now I am trying to do something like:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{has-success: form.email.$valid}">
```

Since I have bootstrap, it will automatically color the label and the input green if the email is valid. But it doesn't work and I am getting this particular error in the console:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.27/$parse/syntax?p0=-&p1=is%20unexpected%2C%20expecting%20%5B%3A%5D&p2=5&p3=%7Bhas-success%3A%20form.email.%24valid%7D&p4=-success%3A%20form.email.%24valid%7D
z/<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js:6:450
```

and so on....

What am I doing wrong? Is it a syntax issue?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Theres a dash in your class name, so use single quotes!

```
ng-class="{'has-success': form.email.$valid}"
```

Comment: What a timing.. Our answers are posted exactly at the same time.. 17-21-21, you were milliseconds ahead of me.. :D

Comment: @PSL - Hah...I know you're always on these Angular questions, gotta be quick!

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking. Now which do I accept? And plus the upvote war is also nearby.

Comment: Wait why can't it be the other way around? I mean, `ng-class='{"has-success": form.email.$valid}'`

Answer (score 13):

It is clearly a parser error, you have invalid syntax due to the presence of `-` in the property name @ `{has-success: form.email.$valid}`. You would need to wrap them in quotes.

Try:-

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-success': form.email.$valid}">
```

Answer (score 5):

If you use '-' in the class name you should cover the class name using single quotes.

```
[ngClass] = "{'some-class': condition}"
```

otherwise can be use

```
[ngClass] = "{someClass : condition}"
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
[ngClass] = "{ 'color-red': isRed}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Though its late and the actual reason for this problem was mentioned by @tymeJV, in some cases, `ngClass`, `ngStyle` and related directives work if the browser tab's cache is cleared. `Clear Cache and Hard reload` or opening in a new tab will work, if you feel the directive is properly defined.